# Can we generate sourcemaps using YUI compressor?

Tags: javascript, yui

Is there a way to generate [sourcemaps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) using YUI compressor? I don't find any option to do that here -- http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/

Answer (score 2):

The YUI Compressor is no longer maintained by the YUI team but instead by a community member. The recommended compressor tool for YUI is [Ugilfy 2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) which has the option to generate source maps.

Comment: With Uglify 2

    uglifyjs myfile.js -o myfile.min.js --source-map myfile.js.map

Answer (score 1):

YUI compressor doesn't support generation of sourcemaps. Here is a nice wiki page that lists the tools and languages that compile to JS supporting source maps -- 
https://github.com/ryanseddon/source-map/wiki/Source-maps%3A-languages,-tools-and-other-info